# ES6 JavaScript - require() CSS into a <script> tag

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, requirejs

I have encountered the following code in ES6:

```
<script>
import CalendarView from "vue-simple-calendar"
import CalendarMathMixin from "vue-simple-calendar/dist/calendar-math-mixin.js"
require("vue-simple-calendar/dist/static/css/default.css")
require("vue-simple-calendar/dist/static/css/holidays-us.css")
... etc ...
</script>
```

The two `import` directives work as expected, but when I uncomment and try the `require()` functions, they do indeed require those files - but I get parse errors on the very first line as if the CSS was being treated as JavaScript.

This is obviously not right.  Am I missing a plugin?  I tried searching similar to "require CSS file in javascript script" but found nothing.

Comment: Why are you trying to include CSS in JavaScript. They should be added to the page using a normal `<link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet">` tag

Comment: AFAIK require.js does not support CSS files.

Comment: There is no way of telling when a CSS file loads, so there would be no point in requiring it with require.js.

Comment: Yes, it seemed new to me but then a lot is.  The referenced instructions are in the readme file here: https://github.com/richardtallent/vue-simple-calendar/